# React Testing Library - testing in isolation and userEvent error

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing tests using Jest and React Testing Library. I had failing tests and I realized that if I change the order of the tests, it will work. I'm guessing this is because the tests aren't properly isolated and one test might affect the other.

I am calling:

```
afterEach(() => {
  cleanup()
  jest.resetAllMocks()
})
```

I have a test that looks like this:

```
it('calls API when submitted', async () => {
   render(<SignUp />)
   fillAllVerificationFieldsWithTestData()
   validateUser.mockResolvedValueOnce({ id: 123 })      
   const signupButton = screen.getByTestId(
      'sign-up-verification-button',
    )  
    userEvent.click(signupButton)     
    await waitFor(() => expect(validateUser).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))      
 })
```

If I create the exact same test or run a similar test after this one with a userEvent.click, I get an error:

**Unable to fire a "mouseMove" event - please provide a DOM element.**

I looked in the  @testing-library/user-event library and I see this code:

```
const userEvent = {
  click(element) {
    const focusedElement = element.ownerDocument.activeElement;
    const wasAnotherElementFocused =
      focusedElement !== element.ownerDocument.body &&
      focusedElement !== element;
    if (wasAnotherElementFocused) {
      fireEvent.mouseMove(focusedElement);
      fireEvent.mouseLeave(focusedElement);
    }
```

I noticed that `element.ownerDocument.activeElement` is null `wasAnotherElementFocused` is true and so it throws the error.

The first time I run the test it isn't null so it works.

Do I need some extra clean up between tests? If I use fireEvent:

```
 fireEvent(signupButton,
      new MouseEvent('click', {
          bubbles: true,
      }),
   )
```

It works but I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong and not isolating my tests correctly.

EDIT:

Here is the code for the fillAllVerificationFieldsWithTestData:

```
export const fillAllVerificationFieldsWithTestData = () => {
  const { given_name, family_name, zip, social, loanNumber } = {
    given_name: screen.getByTestId('given_name'),
    family_name: screen.getByTestId('family_name'),
    zip: screen.getByTestId('zip'),
    social: screen.getByTestId('last4ssn'),
    loanNumber: screen.getByTestId('loan_number'),
  }

  userEvent.type(given_name, 'FirstName')
  userEvent.type(family_name, 'LastName')
  userEvent.type(zip, '77025')
  userEvent.type(social, '1234')
  userEvent.type(loanNumber, '1112223333')
}
```

and `screen` is imported from `@testing-library/react` and I import validate user like this:

```
import { validateUser } from '../../../services/auth'
jest.mock('../../../services/auth')
```

Comment: Have you invested any time in figuring out what test or tests aren't properly encapsulated? It may be less work in the long run to identify and fix the issue than to work around it to perpetuity.

Comment: @DrewReese nope still haven't figured out why the tests aren't properly encapsulated. I've been looking into it all day hence why I posted the question here.

Comment: In the test, what are `validateUser` and `screen`? They aren't defined in the function scope. May explain some of the test leakage.

Comment: @DrewReese I edited the question

Comment: Ah, yeah, `screen` isn't a feature I've ever used but I do recall its existence now. Where/when is `fillAllVerificationFieldsWithTestData` being invoked to fill in the fields when (*after?*) `render(<SignUp />)` is run in the test? Where is `validateUser` being initially mocked?

Comment: @DrewReese ok added an edit :)

Comment: @Eitan I believe you can get weird results when you use the `screen` variable. If jest parallelise your tests, what will the `screen` variable mean? Have you tried using the query methods returned by the `render` function instead of `screen`? Or pass the specific rendered containers into the queries?

Comment: @Doug I tried with the query methods and received the same error. Actually that would be another question, why is it that sometimes the query methods work and not the corresponding screen methods?

Comment: I see only one test in your question? Can you post both the tests and which order works and which doesn't?

Comment: @TarunLalwani if I take that exact same test and copy it, the second one will throw that error.

Comment: @Eitan Have you tried specifying the container in the queries? `const {container} = render(<SignUp />);` and then inside `fillAllVerificationFieldsWithTestData` you can do `getByTestId(container, 'given_name')`

Comment: also, isn't `userEvent.type` async? perhaps you need to wait for it to finish? [source](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event#async-typeelement-text-options)

Comment: @Doug I've used the container query methods with the same issue :(. It also finds the control correctly with the screen functions, I just get the error mentioned above. UserEvent.click isn't async and I would still get the same error because element.ownerDocument.activeElement is null.

Comment: sorry I have no idea! hope you figure it out. If you do, please let me know! :D

Comment: @Doug ok thanks for the replies!

Comment: Would you like to add code of your component under test?

Answer (score 1):

So, I just faced this problem, and what fixed it for me was wrapping any code that causes a React state change (which your `userEvent` code presumably does) in `act`. So, your initial test would look like this:

```
it('calls API when submitted', async () => {
   render(<SignUp />)
   fillAllVerificationFieldsWithTestData()
   validateUser.mockResolvedValueOnce({ id: 123 })      
   const signupButton = screen.getByTestId(
      'sign-up-verification-button',
    )  
    await act(() => userEvent.click(signupButton))     
    await waitFor(() => expect(validateUser).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))      
 })
```

Can you give this a try, applying similar changes to your `fillAllVerificationFieldsWithTestData` function, and let us know how it turned out?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug that was reported in the testing-library/user-event GitHub](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/245) and it [should be fixed as of v11.0.1](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/releases/tag/v11.0.1). It's specific to `userEvent`, which is why `fireEvent` works.

Note that you shouldn't need to call `cleanup` if you're using Jest because [it will get called for you](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#cleanup).